# Use Lenovo's back and forward keys to switch excel tabs

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use Lenovo's back and forward keys to switch excel tabs

The keys are next to the arrows. How do I achieve that??

Comment: This may not solve your problem, but you do know that ctrl+pgdn/pgup will switch sheets, right?

Comment: @PortlandRunner I think only a macro can solve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edit*** - Changed Left to 166 and Right to 167 for the Lenovo Laptop

Under 'ThisWorkBook' use this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.OnKey "{167}", "NextTab"
    Application.OnKey "{166}", "LastTab"
End Sub
```

[image]

Under a new Module put this code:

```
Sub NextTab()
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub

Sub LastTab()
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 1).Activate
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Hurah! This works. The "back" key is 166 and the "forward" key is 167. Maybe you can edit your post so people see it directly when they read you answer. Thanks anyways man.

Comment: @Joan-Diego Rodriguez  Glad I could help and that you could determine what key number you needed.  I updated the post to include the key number.

Comment: Oh just one more question: I am trying to save it as an excel addin to distribute it to my colleagues. I think that I need to change some of the code for it to work but can't figure out what. Do you know?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much experience with add-ins.  If it doesn't work as is, I'd suggest posting a new question and show what you've tried.

Comment: Your solution does work, thank you for that. Its just the saving in an external file. Thank you so much for helping though. Cheers

Comment: This did the trick:
    Private WithEvents App As Application
    
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        Set App = Application
    End Sub

    Private Sub App_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal  Target As Range)
        Application.OnKey "{166}", "LastTab"
        Application.OnKey "{167}", "NextTab"
    End Sub

Comment: Just one more little update that you may want to know about: I have made it so that when scolling left from the first tab, you now jump to the last tab, thus enabling infinite left scroll (similar to right scroll).

    Sub LastTab()
        On Error Resume Next
        Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 1).Activate
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Activate
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but no idea why you'd use the sheet selection change event to set the onkey parameters, this will only work *after* the user has first changed sheet selection, and won't trigger if imported to an addin/personal.
Suggest changing:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange
```

in the first macro to:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open
```